# Receive JSON in Codeigniter's Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Pass json into controller:

```
$.post('xyz_controller/my_function', {url:"dummy data"}, 
    function(data) {
        alert("Success!");
    }, 'json');
```

Within my controller's function (my_function), i receive it as the following:

```
$received = $this->input->post('url');
echo json_encode($received);
```

Unfortunately, `$this->input->post('url')` gives me false.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: are you getting any error .check you console....

Comment: Hmm, It sends as type: GET rather than POST! Wondering, why?

Comment: Yes, i get an error in my console! strange error: Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'

Comment: is it 404 error .... if it is than i am sure its the url that is giving yoy problem... try my answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            $.ajax
    ({
        type    :   "POST", 
        async   :   false, 
        url     :   $phpURL,   
        data    :   "url="+$phpURL,
        success :   function(data)
        {
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            console.log(response)
        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert("error occured");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

PHP Code :

```
$url = "";
$posted_data = $this->input->post();
if(isset($posted_data['url']))                  
{
  $url      = $posted_data['url'];
 }

 echo $url;
```

Answer (score 0):

i think its because you controller's path is not correct

try using `site_url()`

```
$.post('<?php echo site_url("xyz_controller/my_function") ?>', {url:"dummy data"}, 
function(data) {
    alert("Success!");
}, 'json');
```